# How To Test Artisan Commands in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.1

I build an Artisan Command to receive data from a socket, and I want to write a unit-testing for this command but I'm not sure how to write such a test.

Anyone an idea how to write it?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#calling-commands-via-code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814954/laravel-5-console-artisan-command-unit-tests

Comment: This was a better approach for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122816/470749

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is much easier now:

```
<?php

class YourCommandTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->artisan('command', ['param' => 'value']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your assertion ? What do you assert for ?

Comment: That will depend entirely on what you want to happen. There would be a setup before the `$this->artisan()` call and the assertions after it.

Comment: @Mkey My use case was to create X DB records using factories before $this->artisan. Then after I assert X jobs were queued.

Comment: I'm trying to use this same approach, `$this->artisan('custom:command CA')->expectsOutput('Searching')`. But I get an error `Call to a member function expectsOutput() on int`.

Answer (score 47):

Example of test

```php
<?php

class YourCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        Artisan::call('your_command', [
            'command_parameter_1' => 'value1',
            'command_parameter_2' => 'value2',
        ]);

        // If you need result of console output
        $resultAsText = Artisan::output();

        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Found this approach simple and useful for acceptance testing. However, it will not register code coverage for the command itself.

Comment: I run tests with option `--coverage-html` to generate coverage report: `phpunit --coverage-html coverage_path`. And I see coverage of methods what called inside command.

Comment: That's interesting, I really don't get why I'm not getting them covered. Here [my question in case you find it the same case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032285/which-is-an-acceptable-approach-for-testing-commands-in-laravel-5-2-with-phpunit).

Comment: Just for reference: [Coverage Report](https://codeclimate.com/github/timegridio/timegrid/coverage/576ef819af9c910001006757) and [Test Case](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/blob/master/tests/acceptance/commands/SendBusinessReportTest.php)

Comment: @alariva, we have identical versions of phpunit and laravel. I think, problem may be with settings in `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: [this is](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/blob/master/phpunit.xml) my phpunit configuration file, do you see any substantial diff against yours? Thanks for the hints!

Comment: I have not option `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true"`

Comment: I've noteced some work pending in my test case. But I believe the approach works just fine as you say. Thanks for hinting. I will update once I recha to cover those missing lines.

Comment: Just tested and it does register code coverage. Thanks

Comment: I had to set `TestCase::mockConsoleOuput` to `false` to make this work, thanks to [this advice](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26450#issuecomment-449401202).

Answer (score 8):

Maybe useful for someone

**Artisan command Test Cases in Laravel 5.7**

```
public function test_console_command()
{
    $this->artisan('your_command')
         ->expectsQuestion('What is your name?', 'Ajay Makwana')
         ->expectsQuestion('Which language do you program in?', 'PHP')
         ->expectsOutput('Your name is Ajay Makwana and you program in PHP.')
         ->assertExitCode(0);
}
```

https://laravel-news.com/testing-artisan-commands-in-laravel-5-7