# Laravel 5 console (artisan) command unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am migrating my Laravel 4.2 app to 5.1 (starting with 5.0) and am a lot of trouble with my console command unit tests. I have artisan commands for which I need to test the produced console output, proper question/response handling and interactions with other services (using mocks). For all its merits, the Laravel doc is unfortunately silent with regards to testing console commands.

I finally found a way to create those tests, but it feels like a hack with those `setLaravel` and `setApplication` calls.

Is there a better way to do this? I wish I could add my mock instances to the Laravel IoC container and let it create the commands to test with everything properly set. I'm afraid my unit tests will break easily with newer Laravel versions.

Here's my unit test:

Use statements:

```
use Mockery as m;
use App\Console\Commands\AddClientCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;
```

Setup

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->store = m::mock('App\Services\Store');

    $this->command = new AddClientCommand($this->store);

    // Taken from laravel/framework artisan command unit tests
    // (e.g. tests/Database/DatabaseMigrationRollbackCommandTest.php)
    $this->command->setLaravel($this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application'));

    // Required to provide input to command questions (provides command->getHelper())
    // Taken from ??? when I first built my command tests in Laravel 4.2
    $this->command->setApplication($this->app->make('Symfony\Component\Console\Application'));
}
```

Input provided as command arguments. Checks console output

```
public function testReadCommandOutput() {
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($this->command);

    $result = $commandTester->execute([
        '--client-name' => 'New Client',
    ]);

    $this->assertSame(0, $result);
    $templatePath = $this->testTemplate;

    // Check console output
    $this->assertEquals(1, preg_match('/^Client \'New Client\' was added./m', $commandTester->getDisplay()));
}
```

Input provided by simulated keyboard keys

```
public function testAnswerQuestions() {
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($this->command);

    // Simulate keyboard input in console for new client
    $inputs = $this->command->getHelper('question');
    $inputs->setInputStream($this->getInputStream("New Client\n"));
    $result = $commandTester->execute([]);

    $this->assertSame(0, $result);
    $templatePath = $this->testTemplate;

    // Check console output
    $this->assertEquals(1, preg_match('/^Client \'New Client\' was added./m', $commandTester->getDisplay()));
}

protected function getInputStream($input) {
    $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+', false);
    fputs($stream, $input);
    rewind($stream);
    return $stream;
}
```

#### updates

1. This doesn't work in Laravel 5.1 [#11946](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11946)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to comment out my tests involving dynamic input. It seems the Laravel guys don't view properly testing commands as a priority as per the response to the issue: "We're open to PRs. :) 5.1 is closed for such changes though."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have done this before as follows - my console command returns a json response:

```
public function getConsoleResponse()
{
    $kernel = $this->app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
    $status = $kernel->handle(
        $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'test:command', // put your command name here
        ]),
        $output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput
    );

    return json_decode($output->fetch(), true);
}
```

So if you want to put this in it's own command tester class, or as a function within TestCase etc... up to you.

Comment: Looks much better than my solution! And it looks like you have dependency injection working too. I'm not working with Laravel at the moment so I can't test it.

Comment: Took me a good couple of hrs to work it out. But it's one of those snippets I keep in a Gist now!

Comment: I can only get "null" as a return of this

Answer (score 5):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

$output = new BufferedOutput();

Artisan::call('passport:client', [
    '--password' => true,
    '--name' => 'Temp Client',
    '--no-interaction' => true,
], $output);

$stringOutput = $output->fetch();
```

Comment: Nice. This one worked for me, accepted answer didn't.