# Laravel - PHPUnit - Assert output from artisan command / symfony console output

Tags: php, laravel, console, phpunit, console-application

How can I capture the console output of a command in Laravel 5.x.

I am trying to assert various message outputs given specific inputs.

If I can intercept the msg that goes to the console, then maybe I can run the assertion on this?

Comment: I don't know about Laravel, but the docs of the Symfony Console component clearly show how: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#testing-commands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Test Artisan Commands in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611788/how-to-test-artisan-commands-in-laravel-5)